IPipelineBehavior ValidationBehavior doesn't get triggered when registered in MediatR
I'm replacing all exception with Result<T> by the LangExt library. The problem is ValidationBehavior doesn't even get triggered. It used to trigger when the method signature used to be public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators) : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>. So how do I register that ValidationBehavior so it gets triggered, and so I don't have to manually specify the AbstractValidator classes?
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();
builder.Services.AddMediatR(configure =>
{
    configure.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();
    configure.AddRequestPreProcessor(typeof(IRequestPreProcessor<>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<>));
    configure.AddBehavior(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));
    configure.AddBehavior(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(MetricsBehavior<,>));
});

public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators) : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, Result<TResponse>>
    where TRequest : IRequest<Result<TResponse>>
{
    public async Task<Result<TResponse>> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<Result<TResponse>> next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!validators.Any())
        {
            return await next();
        }

        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
        var validationResults = await Task.WhenAll(validators.Select(v => v.ValidateAsync(context, cancellationToken)));

        var failures = validationResults
            .Where(r => r.Errors.Count != 0)
            .SelectMany(r => r.Errors)
            .ToList();

        if (failures.Count != 0)
        {
            return new Result<TResponse>(new ValidationException(failures));
        }

        return await next();
    }
}


I found those related posts https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/305#issuecomment-417002645 and https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/626, however I'm still unable to do return new Result<TResponse>(new ValidationException(failures)); via System.Reflection

It seems, the ValidationBehavior in your MediatR pipeline isn't triggering because its type signature was changed to IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, Result<TResponse>>, but it may still be registered for TResponse directly. To fix this, ensure the behavior is registered with the correct Result<TResponse> signature in MediatR. Also, confirm that validators are registered with builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>() so they are recognized by the ValidationBehavior. This alignment should resolve the issue.

@MdFaridUddinKiron yes, that's the issue. If IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, Result<TResponse>> is changed back to IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>, and return new Result<TResponse>(new ValidationException(failures)); is replaced with System.Reflection, it works. https://pastebin.com/vNkjZ6dF (this works), however it throws when it's unable to cast the return type to TResponse, which is why I need a proper System.Reflection code that calls return new Result<TResponse>(new ValidationException(failures)); instead

Why don't you just  dynamically create an instance of Result when the validation fails. This can be done using Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate the Result object, passing the ValidationException as an argument. Have you tried anything like that? Or how you are trying to convert the response.

@MdFaridUddinKiron, I'm trying to convert the response if it's not Result<T> that comes from LanguageExt.Core

@MdFaridUddinKiron, https://pastebin.com/0vZWYJrQ "If TResponse is not Result, or no constructor is found" -> this should not be throwing but rather converting the response to Result<T>

You should probably change the signature of your class to something like this :
public class ValidationPreProcessor<TRequest> : IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest>{

private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

public ValidationPreProcessor(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
{
    _validators = validators;
}

public async Task Process(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
    var failures = _validators
        .Select(v => v.Validate(context))
        .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
        .Where(f => f != null)
        .ToList();

    if (failures.Any())
    {
        throw new ValidationException(failures);
    }
} }

as for how to register it
public class Startup 
{

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
    services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();

    // Register pipeline behaviors
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(AuthorizationBehavior<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(PerformanceBehavior<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(UnhandledExceptionBehavior<,>));

    // Register request pre-processors and post-processors
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestPreProcessor<>), typeof(ValidationPreProcessor<>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestPostProcessor<,>), typeof(LoggingPostProcessor<,>));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
} 
}

you can fin more here https://argosco.io/using-ipipelinebehavior-irequestpreprocessor-and-irequestpostprocessor-in-a-net-core-api/net/
